how to change the color of my ascii art in emu8086?
I created a simple project for my assignment and the only thing left is to change the color of the frog ASCII art (which is named "Frog") into green and I don't know how to do so. This is my code:
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
            
; Display name
mov dx, offset Jas
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

; Display frog
mov dx, offset Frog
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
                  
mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h


"the only thing left is to change the color" Well there's your first error: you must take this into account from the very beginning. The DOS output functions don't care about any coloring at all! You'll have to use BIOS functions or else write to video memory directly. And please show us the whole program so we could at least start helping you...
